# tf frames in different time epoch from ros time?

Tags: navigation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to tackle the following warning when running Navigation:

```
[ WARN] [1368081077.201722266]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration
[ WARN] [1368081077.401579990]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 1368081077.4015, global_pose stamp: 136.4000, tolerance: 0.3000
```

The transform timed out because the time & the pose stamp are extremely different. Are they in different time epochs? If so, how can that be solved?

Thanks,

Ernest

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62435/tf-frames-in-different-time-epoch-from-ros-time?/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You're probably running Gazebo and missing the `use_sim_time` parameter. Try the following:

1. `roscore`
2. `rosparam set use_sim_time true`
3. *Now* start launching the rest of your system.

The explanation is that the navigation stack was probably launched before the `use_sim_time` parameter was set (so it uses wall time: 1368081077.4015), and the thing publishing the TF transforms was launched afterwards (so it uses sim time: 136.4000).

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-05-09**:
spot on! that solved the problem. Thank you very much.